# Excel VBA ElseIf query

Tags: vba, if-statement

The following little piece of vba returns the required value in cell B2. I thought by changing the Range to ("A:A") and ("B:B") I could get it to run through an entire spreadsheet. However it fails to run when I try this. The full list has 15 countries so an IF function copied down column B won't work.
Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

```
    Sub test()

    Dim Country As String, ID As Integer
    Country = Range("A2").Value

    If Country = "France" Then
        ID = 1
    ElseIf Country = "Germany" Then
        ID = 2
    ElseIf Country = "Spain" Then
        ID = 3
    ElseIf Country = "Italy" Then
        ID = 4
    Else
        Code = 0
    End If

    Range("B2").Value = ID

    End sub
```

Answer (score 4):

Commenter above is correct, you should look into using the select statement, but I'd be a liar if I said I didn't use a bunch of ElseIf statements when I'm feeling lazy... Anyway, I'm assuming you want this to check the value in column A and return the ID code for each cell in A in column B.  What you need is a for each loop... try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim Country As String, ID As Integer

Dim Rng As Range
Dim Cel As Range

Set Rng = Range("A:A")

For Each Cel In Rng

    Country = Cel.Value

    If Country = "France" Then
        ID = 1
    ElseIf Country = "Germany" Then
        ID = 2
    ElseIf Country = "Spain" Then
        ID = 3
    ElseIf Country = "Italy" Then
        ID = 4
    End If

    Cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = ID

Next Cel

End Sub
```

So what you're doing is looping through each Cell (Cel) in the Range (Rng) of column A.  When you return your ID, you're just offseting the Cell (Cel) from column A to the Cell in column B (Cel.Offset(0, 1)).

This will work, but it might be kinda slow because it will cycle through all ranges.  What you could also do is find the last row somehow.  There are more interesting ways to do it, but if I were you I'd just loop through using an integer counter:

```
Sub test()

Dim Country As String, ID As Integer

Dim intCounter As Integer

intCounter = 1

Do Until Cells(intCounter, 1).Value = ""

    Country = Cells(intCounter, 1).Value

    If Country = "France" Then
        ID = 1
    ElseIf Country = "Germany" Then
        ID = 2
    ElseIf Country = "Spain" Then
        ID = 3
    ElseIf Country = "Italy" Then
        ID = 4
    End If

    Cells(intCounter, 2).Value = ID

    intCounter = intCounter + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

The above would have the exact same results, but you wouldn't have to go through every cell in column A, only the cells that are populated.

Edit:

Since it was mentioned bellow, I thought I'd toss in an example of how to do this with a collection:

```
Sub test()

Dim intCounter As Integer

Dim countries As Collection
Set countries = New Collection

'Here is where you'd add all your country codes:
countries.Add 1, "France"
countries.Add 2, "Germany"
countries.Add 3, "Spain"
countries.Add 4, "Italy"
countries.Add 232, "Ireland"

'Now just loop through
intCounter = 1
Do Until Cells(intCounter, 1).Value = ""
    'Next line returns the numeric value (the item) from countries based
    'on the value contained in the cell to the left in column A and writes
    'it to column B.
    Cells(intCounter, 2).Value = countries(Cells(intCounter, 1).Value)
    intCounter = intCounter + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

That is actually how I'd perform this kind of task.  I'd also consider placing `On Error Resume Next` before the `Cells(intCounter, 2).value = countries...` line, and `On Error GoTo 0` after that line.  This will skip any cells that had a country string not contained in the collection.  The on error resume next statement simply tells the compiler to ignore the next error it finds.  Since we are only looking for an error on that next line, we turn error handling off using the on error goto 0 line on the next line.  It is handy when using collections.  Based on these fundamentals you can effectively "test" a collection for an item using some creativity.  Depending on how reliable I thoguht the input on the worksheet was, I might also use `Trim()` on the string returned from the cell in column A to remove any accidental extra spaces.

Comment: +1 good answer plus explanations. Consider using `StrComp()` to compare String values as you can specify how to compare them using vba constants.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. I went with your second suggestion and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help but I'd recommend reviewing and understanding all the methods I presented as well as the other answers here.  There is a ton of good information especially if you're just starting out.  Learn Select, Dictionaries, and Collections and master the world!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a `For` loop. Take a look at `Select Case` statement as well, it's better than multiple `If`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be easier for you to maintain

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim Country As Object

    Set Country = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Country.Add "France", 1
    Country.Add "Germany", 2
    Country.Add "Spain", 3
    Country.Add "Italy", 4

    For Each Cell In Range("A2:A7")
        If Country.Exists(Cell.Value) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Country(Cell.Value)
        Else
            Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
        End If
    Next

    Country.RemoveAll
    Set Country = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: @user3360480 Using something like this would be a good idea.  If you plan on continuing to learn to code.  Might be even better to use a collection.  Pretty similar to what he described above.  To create it you'd use `Dim myCollection As Collection` Then `Set myCollection = New Collection` then to add things to it `myCollection.Add item, "index as string"`, so if you wanted to add France as 1 you would do `myCollection.Add 1, "France"` then you would be able to retrive that value by searching your collection for the country name... `ID = myCollection("France")' which would return 1.

Comment: Hmm ... how is using `Collection` better than `Dictionary` for the above case? Whatever little that I know about VBScript, dictionary is much easier to work with and offers loads of useful features. Stuff like removing all items in one go without destroying the object, implicitly adding of items, better performance, etc.

Comment: They are, at least in VB.net, the same thing actually.  A dictionary is just a modified collection.  I'm not 100% on the implementation in the scripting object library, but I'd imagine it is the same in VBA.  I see collections used much, much more often than dictionaries, but there isn't really much wrong or supperior about either, with the possible exception being that you aren't dependent on setting a reference for the scripting library to use a collection.  Of course you can get away with using late binding like you did in your example, but that is somewhat discouraged now.

Comment: In VBA, you would have to make a reference to use Collections also unless you late bind it. Not sure about VB.NET, but dictionary is much more useful and easy to handle as you get loads of freebies from the scripting language itself, which a collection doesn't have. Read this [excellent article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/A_3391-Using-the-Dictionary-Class-in-VBA.html).

Comment: I think you need to double check the collection thing in vba.  It's native both there and VB.net, at least as of 6.0.  Dictionary does give you some more functionality, as does the scripting library in general.  I'm not sure how it works in VB script though, I know you pretty much have to late bind everything and I don't know if you have to late bind a collection or not, but you can declare a collection in VBA without a reference or late binding, of that I can assure you.  I've been working with them all day.

Comment: Just check the references in your VBA IDE ... see anything strange?

Comment: Again, I just double checked. I don't... Just the normal references. I was mistaken about it being native though, it doesn't operate like string or integer, you have to declare and instantiate it, so it must be part of a library, but I maintain and I'm seeing that you don't have to set a reference to a library for it, nor does VBA automatically set it for you, it's part of the references that already exist in VBA by default. For the record, the default seems to be: Visual Basic For Applications, Microsoft Excel 14.0 (if excel), and OLE Automation. Thought I should add that this is Excel 2010